# office.js cell change event

Tags: office-js, excel-addins

In Office.js, we have an event for the document selection change `DocumentSelectionChanged`

```js
document.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.DocumentSelectionChanged, function() {});
```

Do we have an event for cell value change? So we want to know when a cell value is updated.

Answer (score 1):

The currently supported values for `EventType` are listed here in the docs: https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/eventtype-enumeration. Seems like perhaps the [bindingDataChanged](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/binding.bindingdatachangedevent) event would work for your scenario?

Comment: Great minds think alike, and in parallel it seems. :)

Comment: Indeed, so it seems :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a [Binding](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/bindingcollection) for the range/cell, you can register for the [BindingDataChangedEvent](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/excel/bindingdatachangedeventargs) which lets you know when actual data was edited.

Comment: What if I have any bindings. In the worksheet we have a normal cell with formula and user override the formula with some value. we want to know when that happens.

Comment: You'll need to add a binding for that cell in order to start receiving change notifications.